# vue-star-rating TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at listToStyles.js:26

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Getting this error while calling getRating function in Vue. I'm using the Vue-star-rating package in laravel. don't understand what is the problem.

```
 getRating(){
                    var pathArray = location.pathname.split('/');
                    var pid = pathArray[2];
                    fetch(`/api/rating/${pid}`)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(res => {
                        var mydata = res.data;
                        this.totaluser = mydata.length;
                        var sum = 0;
                        for(var i=0; i < mydata.length; i++){
                            sum += parseFloat(mydata[i]['rating']);
                        } 
                        var avg = sum/mydata.length;
                        this.totalrate = parseFloat(avg.toFixed(1));
                        var bar1 = 0;
                        var bar2 = 0;
                        var bar3 = 0;
                        var bar4 = 0;
                        var bar5 = 0;
                        for(var j = 0; j < mydata.length; j++){
                            if(parseInt(mydata[j]['rating']) == '1'){
                                bar1 += 1;
                            }
                            if(parseInt(mydata[j]['rating']) == '2'){
                                bar2 += 1;
                            }
                            if(parseInt(mydata[j]['rating']) == '3'){
                                bar3 += 1;
                            }
                            if(parseInt(mydata[j]['rating']) == '4'){
                                bar4 += 1;
                            }
                            if(parseInt(mydata[j]['rating']) == '5'){
                                bar5 += 1;
                            }
                        }
                        $('.bar-1').css('width', bar1+'%');
                        $('.bar-2').css('width', bar2+'%');
                        $('.bar-3').css('width', bar3+'%');
                        $('.bar-4').css('width', bar4+'%');
                        $('.bar-5').css('width', bar5+'%');
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)

                    });
                },
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined     at listToStyles.js:26

Hope you guys give me some advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `myData` is undefined.
You can write a more safe code as following

```js
getRating(){
                    var pathArray = location.pathname.split('/');
                    var pid = pathArray[2];
                    fetch(`/api/rating/${pid}`)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(res => {
                        var mydata = res.data || []; // sets myData to empty array if res.data is undefined
                        this.totaluser = mydata.length;

                        var sum = 0;
                        for(var i=0; i < mydata.length; i++){
                            sum += parseFloat(mydata[i]['rating']);
                        } 
                        var avg = sum/mydata.length; // this will produce error if mydata.length is zero
                        this.totalrate = parseFloat(avg.toFixed(1));
                        var bar1 = 0;
                        var bar2 = 0;
                        var bar3 = 0;
                        var bar4 = 0;
                        var bar5 = 0;
                        for(var j = 0; j < mydata.length; j++){
                            if(parseInt(mydata[j]['rating']) == '1'){
                                bar1 += 1;
                            }
                            if(parseInt(mydata[j]['rating']) == '2'){
                                bar2 += 1;
                            }
                            if(parseInt(mydata[j]['rating']) == '3'){
                                bar3 += 1;
                            }
                            if(parseInt(mydata[j]['rating']) == '4'){
                                bar4 += 1;
                            }
                            if(parseInt(mydata[j]['rating']) == '5'){
                                bar5 += 1;
                            }
                        }
                        $('.bar-1').css('width', bar1+'%');
                        $('.bar-2').css('width', bar2+'%');
                        $('.bar-3').css('width', bar3+'%');
                        $('.bar-4').css('width', bar4+'%');
                        $('.bar-5').css('width', bar5+'%');
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)

                    });
                },
```

Comment: Thanks, brother the error is gone but can you figure out why the data ain't fetch???   this is my API Route       Route::get('/rating/{id}', 'API\RatingController@getrating')->name('getrating');                                                                                                            ---and this is the controller                                                                                             public function getrating($id) {
        return RatingResource::collection(Rating::all())->where('business_id', $id);
    }

Comment: I'm sorry, I currently have a little to no knowledge about how API servers and backend works :(
May be you can post another question in stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

all the 'length' things you do is on res.data you are getting and that one is undefined as it seems. try to make a console log and be sure that your api gives you what you want to make res.data.length